# PHP: Next delivery date

Tags: php, date, datetime, intervals

PHP Newb, so excuse the simplicity of the question.

I am attempting to create a little echo that shows the 'next delivery date' based on two parameters: a start date and an interval (in either days or weeks).

What I am specifically wanting is to be able to enter, for instance, today as the 'start date' and the interval (say, '3 weeks'), and have the script return "your next delivery is on XXX", with XXX being the next upcoming 3-week interval upcoming in the future up to and including two days before, when it switches to "tomorrow". On the actual date, it moves to the next period (the delivery cannot be ordered on the delivery date) into infinity or some realistic date in the future (the next 5 years?)

Is this possible?  I've looked through previous questions, and it seems reasonably trivial to add a locked in date (a date + a set period into the future) but I didn't come across anything that looks at the current date and thinks about what the next recurrence would be... hence my ask here.

Comment: It is unclear as to how you specify what the available delivery dates are.

Comment: @MikeBrant It doesn't really matter - it can be a string, it can be selected from html5 date input or some sort of JS. It can be as simple as ```echo stftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime('+3 weeks'));``` Now the question would be what kind of goal is the author trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmmm.  Ask your question again. I was with you up till "your next delivery is on XXX".  From that point on, it's not clear on what you are looking for...

Comment: I agree with @zipkit here was with you until same exact point.  At that point, you seem to infer that there is some specific set of dates upon which deliveries are available. If there is not and you just want to project dates based on some input, it is pretty simple with `DateTime`, `DateInterval`, and `DatePeriod` classes.

Comment: Sorry... I knew I'd be adding more fog than clarity.

If I have a start date 2015/ 07/21, and a delivery period of every 3 weeks, ongoing, how do I show the next, and only the next, upcoming delivery date?

Comment: Better.  But still not quite there.  Are you saying you only have a delivery period ONCE every three weeks? or are you saying you only want to display output for all deliveries scheduled within the next three weeks (beyond that don't display anything...)?

Comment: So let me summarize.  The knowns are when a user's start date was (not related to current date at all), and the interval (which always starts from start date) upon which deliveries are made.  You want to take the current date and compare it against this series of dates to determine when the next delivery date is?

Comment: You create an array of all delivery dates.  Sort the array, then only display the first one?  I'm not at all understanding what goal you are trying to achieve. .

Comment: I'll get there ;)

Enter a date.  Any date.
Enter an interval. Any interval.
Return a single 'next' recurring date based on the above, ongoing.  In other words, when the 'next' becomes 'today', start displaying the 'next' into the future, but simply the one iteration.

Comment: Awesome, short sentences, each one capturing a single coherent thought.  great start...  Alternatively, have you considered use case description?  "snip runs a delivery service.  He wants generate a report daily that shows all the upcoming deliveries. The report will show, Today: delivery to Joe and Susan, Tomorrow, delivery to ralph, Thursday.."

Comment: @zipzit  that's not exactly what I am after, but good thought.  Here is the case.   I have delivery areas: the trucks are in certain areas on certain days, with certain intervals (weekly, bi-weekly, every 3 or 4 weeks).  I am attempting to create a 'look up your postal code to see when we are in your area again' solution.

Comment: A bit more data: PHP Version 5.4.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DatePeriod](http://php.net/dateperiod) for this. `DatePeriod` will take a `DateTime` object as a start date, for the first parameter, a `DateInterval` object as the interval on which to repeat, for the second parameter, and a `DateTime` object or integer representing the ending date or number of recurrences for the period.

So for example, if you have a start date of today and a 3 week interval you can get the delivery date with something like this...

```
$start    = new DateTime('today');
$interval = new DateInterval('P3W');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, 1, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

foreach($period as $deliveryDate) {
    echo "Next delivery date: " . $deliveryDate->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

This should give you something like...

```
Next delivery date: 2015-08-11
```

Comment: `DatePeriod()`  way cool function. This function essentially creates a handy array of all dates within the interval time period.  Thanks for sharing.  I'm not sure that's exactly what @Snip is asking, but I can see where I might use it in the future.

Comment: added a closing bracket at line: `echo "Next delivery date: " . $deliveryDate->format('Y-m-d');}`, and seems to work like a charm!

Comment: You mean on top of the closing bracket that exists on the following line?

Answer (score 0):

You strong strongly consider using DateTime, DateInterval, DatePeriod classes for this.  That might look like this:

```
$start_date = '2015-07-21'; // or whatever date you get from some location
// create a DateTime object that represents start of sequence
$start_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date);
// create a DateTime object representing the current date/
$current_datetime = new DateTime('today');    
$date_interval = new DateInterval('P3W'); // for 3 weeks
// determine end date for DatePeriod object that will later be used
// this is no further out than current date plus the interval
$end_datetime = new DateTime('today');
$end_datetime->add($date_interval);

$date_period = new DatePeriod($start_datetime, $interval, $end_datetime, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

// at this point, you simply need to grab last item from $date_period to get next delivery
// unfortunately there is no array access on this object, so you just need to iterate until the end
foreach($date_period as $dp) {
    $next_delivery = $dp;
}

// echo date from next delivery
echo $next_delivery->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: This line seems to give an error:

`$date_period = new DatePeriod($start_datetime, $interval, $end_datetime, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);`

Comment: This is the error message:


`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DatePeriod::__construct(): This constructor accepts either (DateTime, DateInterval, int) OR (DateTime, DateInterval, DateTime) OR (string) as arguments.' in /home/johnglh1/public_html/Date-increment.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/johnglh1/public_html/Date-increment.php(19): DatePeriod->__construct(Object(DateTime), NULL, Object(DateTime), 1) #1 {main} thrown in /home/johnglh1/public_html/Date-increment.php on line 19`

Comment: @Snip It seems DateInterval object was not instantiated for some reason in your setup. You must be on PHP 5.2. DateInterval was introduced in 5.3

Comment: Sorry for the slow response: holidays.      
A bit more data: PHP Version 5.4.28... so I guess that wasn't it?